# How to create a collection of jQuery elements and append them to the DOM?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-mobile, append, documentfragment

I'm looping over a list and need to create a [jQuery Mobile radio button](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/) for each list element. All radio buttons should go inside a `div class="radio-controls"` which - once finished - are appended to the DOM.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
    var label = $("<label/>").attr("data-" + $.mobile.ns + "iconpos", "notext");
      barrel = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < myListitems.length; i += 1) {
      var item = myListitems[i];

      barrel.push(
          $("<input type='radio' name='radio-" + this.uuid + "' value='radio-" + this.uuid + "-" + i +"' />" )
            .wrap(label)
            .checkboxradio()
        );
      }
    }
```

After the loop I have an jQuery array, which I need to append.

But [makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) fails and returns

```
context is undefined
```

inside jQuery

```
 if ( ( context.ownerDocument || context ) !== document ) {
```

which is said to be caused by the array not consisting of elements selected from the document (mine are still not added to the DOM), while `document.createFragement` does not work, because I think I cannot add jQuery objects to a fragment. Doing this:

```
 var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

 // in my loop
 bullet = $("<input type='radio' name='radio-" + this.uuid + "' value='radio-" + this.uuid + "-" + i +"' />" )
     .wrap(label)
     .checkboxradio()
 fragment.appendChild( bullet );

 // after loop, add to document 
 fragment[o.bulletsPos === "top" ? prependTo : appendTo](el);
```

returns this error:

```
 Value does not implement interface Node.
```

**Question**:
Is there a way to generate a collection of jQuery items and append this to the DOM? Of course I can insert every item one-by-one, but I want to create the whole thing dynamic and insert once.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you make a fiddle? I know you can create an array of elements with the `.map()` function, then append that entire array to an element. I made a quick fiddle, does it help (I might be missing the mark on this one)? http://jsfiddle.net/558qq/

Comment: Trying to update your fiddle. 1sec

Comment: @tymeJV: [http://jsfiddle.net/558qq/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/558qq/1/) but I just saw, that maybe it will work if not wrapping `$()` around collection. 1sec

Comment: Change that last `append` to `$(document.body).append(collection)` :: http://jsfiddle.net/558qq/2/

Comment: yup. that works. I'm loosing the jQuery Mobile styling though... anyway. Please make it an answer, so I can check. Thanks!

Comment: With mobile styling I believe you have to do an extra step and refresh the elements, a quick google search should verify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was able to get this to append with the following sample code:

```
var collection = [];
var elem;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i+=1) {
    elem = $("<span />").attr("class","foo-"+i).text("hello");
    collection.push(elem);
}
console.log(collection);
// the "context" error
//$(collection).appendTo(document.body);
$(document.body).append(collection);
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/558qq/3/